# Aggregate query for drawing temporal statistic

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

I used to write simple Mongo queries, but this time I had to create an aggregate query. The purpose is to draw temporal statistic on the main page of my web app.

I'm not confident about his performance in production environment, so I'm looking for advice and review about this one.

```
db.runs.aggregate([
    {$project: {
        "month": {
                $cond: [
                    {$ifNull: ["$startTime", false]},
                    {$month:"$startTime"},
                    -1
                ]   
            },
        "year": {
                $cond: [
                    {$ifNull: ["$startTime", false]},
                    {$year:"$startTime"},
                    -1
                ]
            },
        "nbItem": 1,
        "cleanUp.nb": 1,
        "startTime": 1
    }},
    {$match: {
        "startTime" : {$ne:null}
    }},
    {$group: {
        "_id": {
            "month":"$month",
            "year":"$year"
        },
        "nbRun":{$sum:1},
        "sumItem":{$sum:"$nbItem"},
        "sumInserted":{$sum:"$cleanUp.nb"}
    }}
])
```

As expected the result looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "month" : 2,
        "year" : 2017
    },
    "nbRun" : 5,
    "sumItem" : 567372,
    "sumInserted" : 35107
}
{
    "_id" : {
        "month" : 10,
        "year" : 2016
    },
    "nbRun" : 3,
    "sumItem" : 677722,
    "sumInserted" : 16090
}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here your doing something very redondant :

if you move the **`$match`** stage at the begining of the aggregation, you no longer need to check wether `startTime` is null in your project stage:

Plus, a **`$match`** stage should always be at the beginning of you aggregation pipeline, as it will reduce the number of documents treated in the next stage. 
from [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/):

> **Pipeline Optimization**
>
> Place the $match as early in the aggregation pipeline as possible.
>   Because $match limits the total number of documents in the aggregation
>   pipeline, earlier $match operations minimize the amount of processing
>   down the pipe.
>
> If you place a $match at the very beginning of a
>   pipeline, the query can take advantage of indexes like any other
>   db.collection.find() or db.collection.findOne().

so your query becomes:

```
db.runs.aggregate([
    {$match: {
        "startTime" : {$ne:null}
    }},
    {$project: {
        "month": {$month:"$startTime"},
        "year": {$year:"$startTime"},
        "nbItem": 1,
        "cleanUp.nb": 1,
        "startTime": 1
    }},
    {$group: {
        "_id": {
            "month":"$month",
            "year":"$year"
        },
        "nbRun": {$sum:1},
        "sumItem": {$sum:"$nbItem"},
        "sumInserted": {$sum:"$cleanUp.nb"}
    }}
])
```

Now we can push it even further by merging the **`$project`** and the **`$group`** stage into a single **`$group`** stage like this :

```
db.runs.aggregate([
    {$match: {
        "startTime" : {$ne:null}
    }},
    {$group: {
        "_id": {
            "month": {$month: "$startTime"},
            "year": {$year: "$startTime"}
        },
        "nbRun": {$sum:1},
        "sumItem": {$sum:"$nbItem"},
        "sumInserted": {$sum:"$cleanUp.nb"}
    }}
])
```

The query should run faster and is now way more readable.

Finally, you can look at the [explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#example-aggregate-method-explain-option) of the query to understand exactly what happens. Make sure that the `startTime` field is properly indexed.

If the query still does not run fast enough, consider adding the field `year` and `month` directly in your documents to get rid of the **`$year`** and **`$month`** operators